# How to run springboot app with Hikari datasource without HikariPool shutdown initiated

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, maven, hikaricp

I have a spring boot app with maven and use Hikari data source to connect Mysql database. But when I run spring boot application, the HikariPool shutdown initiated happen as below:

```
C:\Users\Admin\.jdks\corretto-11.0.12\bin\java.exe -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=58795:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2\bin" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PiratedMovieWeb\target\classes;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PiratedMovieWeb\lib\javax.jms.jar;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PiratedMovieWeb\lib\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PiratedMovieWeb\lib\javax.resource.jar;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PiratedMovieWeb\lib\javax.servlet.jar;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PiratedMovieWeb\lib\javax.ejb.jar;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PiratedMovieWeb\lib\javax.servlet.jsp.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client\2.5.5\spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.5.5\spring-boot-starter-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.5.5\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.6\logback-classic-1.2.6.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.6\logback-core-1.2.6.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.14.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.14.1\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.32\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.28\snakeyaml-1.28.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\jakarta.mail\1.6.7\jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.5.2\spring-security-config-5.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.10\spring-aop-5.3.10.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.10\spring-context-5.3.10.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.5.2\spring-security-core-5.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\5.5.2\spring-security-crypto-5.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.10\spring-expression-5.3.10.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-oauth2-client\5.5.2\spring-security-oauth2-client-5.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-oauth2-core\5.5.2\spring-security-oauth2-core-5.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.5.2\spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\oauth2-oidc-sdk\9.9.1\oauth2-oidc-sdk-9.9.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\github\stephenc\jcip\jcip-annotations\1.0-1\jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\content-type\2.1\content-type-2.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\lang-tag\1.5\lang-tag-1.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-oauth2-jose\5.5.2\spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\nimbus-jose-jwt\9.10.1\nimbus-jose-jwt-9.10.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.5.5\spring-boot-devtools-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.5.5\spring-boot-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.5.5\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.20\lombok-1.18.20.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.4.7\json-smart-2.4.7.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\2.4.7\accessors-smart-2.4.7.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.1\asm-9.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.22\byte-buddy-1.10.22.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.10\spring-core-5.3.10.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.10\spring-jcl-5.3.10.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.5.6\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.5.5\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.5.5\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.32.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.27.0-GA\javassist-3.27.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.2.3.Final\jandex-2.2.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.3\dom4j-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.5\jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.5\txw2-2.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.5.5\spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.5.5\spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.10\spring-orm-5.3.10.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.10\spring-aspects-5.3.10.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.5.5\spring-boot-starter-web-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.5.5\spring-boot-starter-json-2.5.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.12.5\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.12.5\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.12.5\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.10\spring-web-5.3.10.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.10\spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.1.1\javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.12.5\jackson-annotations-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.12.5\jackson-core-2.12.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\io\jsonwebtoken\jjwt\0.9.1\jjwt-0.9.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.9\spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.10\spring-beans-5.3.10.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.10\spring-tx-5.3.10.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.4.5\HikariCP-3.4.5.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.32\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.16\mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.2\gson-2.8.2.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-annotations\1.6.2\swagger-annotations-1.6.2.jar com.example.piratedmovieweb.PiratedMovieWebApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.5)

2021-11-08 21:09:15.272  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.p.PiratedMovieWebApplication         : Starting PiratedMovieWebApplication using Java 11.0.12 on DESKTOP-OFQLT9I with PID 11796 (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PiratedMovieWeb\target\classes started by Admin in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PiratedMovieWeb)
2021-11-08 21:09:15.273  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.p.PiratedMovieWebApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-08 21:09:15.307  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-11-08 21:09:15.307  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-11-08 21:09:15.717  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-11-08 21:09:15.732  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 9 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-11-08 21:09:15.910 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver found in Thread context class loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@13c357f2
2021-11-08 21:09:15.977 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - configuration:
2021-11-08 21:09:15.979 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : allowPoolSuspension.............false
2021-11-08 21:09:15.979 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : autoCommit......................true
2021-11-08 21:09:15.979 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : catalog.........................none
2021-11-08 21:09:15.979 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionInitSql...............none
2021-11-08 21:09:15.979 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTestQuery.............none
2021-11-08 21:09:15.979 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTimeout...............30000
2021-11-08 21:09:15.979 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSource......................none
2021-11-08 21:09:15.979 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceClassName.............none
2021-11-08 21:09:15.980 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceJNDI..................none
2021-11-08 21:09:15.980 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
2021-11-08 21:09:15.980 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : driverClassName................."com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
2021-11-08 21:09:15.980 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : exceptionOverrideClassName......none
2021-11-08 21:09:15.980 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckProperties...........{}
2021-11-08 21:09:15.980 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckRegistry.............none
2021-11-08 21:09:15.980 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : idleTimeout.....................600000
2021-11-08 21:09:15.980 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : initializationFailTimeout.......1
2021-11-08 21:09:15.980 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : isolateInternalQueries..........false
2021-11-08 21:09:15.980 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/piratedmovie?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : leakDetectionThreshold..........0
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maxLifetime.....................1800000
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maximumPoolSize.................5
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricRegistry..................none
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricsTrackerFactory...........none
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : minimumIdle.....................5
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : password........................<masked>
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : readOnly........................false
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : registerMbeans..................false
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : scheduledExecutor...............none
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : schema..........................none
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : threadFactory...................internal
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : transactionIsolation............default
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : username........................"root"
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : validationTimeout...............5000
2021-11-08 21:09:15.981  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-11-08 21:09:16.078 DEBUG 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@405e1d52
2021-11-08 21:09:16.080  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-11-08 21:09:16.141  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-11-08 21:09:16.180  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-11-08 21:09:16.182 DEBUG 11796 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
2021-11-08 21:09:16.189 DEBUG 11796 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@56b5de06
2021-11-08 21:09:16.193 DEBUG 11796 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@1788d43d
2021-11-08 21:09:16.197 DEBUG 11796 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@26d5246a
2021-11-08 21:09:16.202 DEBUG 11796 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@77a72b72
2021-11-08 21:09:16.202 DEBUG 11796 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - After adding stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2021-11-08 21:09:16.284  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-11-08 21:09:16.362  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2021-11-08 21:09:16.746  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-11-08 21:09:16.752  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-08 21:09:16.872  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-11-08 21:09:16.890  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.p.PiratedMovieWebApplication         : Started PiratedMovieWebApplication in 1.93 seconds (JVM running for 2.75)
2021-11-08 21:09:16.898  INFO 11796 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-08 21:09:16.901  INFO 11796 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-11-08 21:09:16.901 DEBUG 11796 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Before shutdown stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2021-11-08 21:09:16.902 DEBUG 11796 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@405e1d52: (connection evicted)
2021-11-08 21:09:16.904 DEBUG 11796 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@56b5de06: (connection evicted)
2021-11-08 21:09:16.904 DEBUG 11796 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@1788d43d: (connection evicted)
2021-11-08 21:09:16.904 DEBUG 11796 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@26d5246a: (connection evicted)
2021-11-08 21:09:16.905 DEBUG 11796 --- [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@77a72b72: (connection evicted)
2021-11-08 21:09:16.905 DEBUG 11796 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - After shutdown stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
2021-11-08 21:09:16.905  INFO 11796 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I configured properties file as below and can get data query by using Unit Test normally:

```
# =============Database config==================
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/piratedmovie?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456_
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
# ==============JPA / HIBERNATE=================
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.main.web-application-type=none

logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG 
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE
```

I also add spring-boot-starter-web, HikariCP, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa as many people advice but cannot resolve this issues.

Anyone can give solution for me to fix this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `spring.main.web-application-type=none` you are telling Boot not to start the embedded servlet container. So, your application initializes and starts and then shutsdown. Comment out this property and it should start baring any other issues.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried remove this line before but other issue happen after that:
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.

Comment: Can you show your 'main' class? Is your main class annotated with @SpringBootApplication?